# Web-based stock/project manager

Tags: project-management, document-management, office, planning

I've searched in old threads and also on Google. I found several interesting applications, but for a specific task. I'm looking for a single web application with these features:

- very simple stock management: define products, check-in, check-out
- project planner: start-end date, milestones, daily tasks
- projects life-cycle management: keep track of the project's state. Usually the cycle is: specifications, quote, purchase order, shipping bill, pro-forma invoice, invoice. But (almost) any of these phases could be skipped.
- office management: the best would be if it might use LibreOffice templates to fill up quotes and invoices
- allow simple queries: how many orders are shipped but not invoiced yet? how many projects will be open at the same time on that date?

As said before, I found at least one application for each feature. But I would like to have only ONE to help me in my job.